# Select rows from table representing an object's changing of state ignoring no-change rows

Tags: database, sqlite

In a sqlite database I have the following table:

```
id   object   val1 val2   'time stamp'
1      Z      100  102        53
2      Z      100  102        54
3      Z      100  103        55
4      A      99   123        23
5      A      23   245        35
6      A      23   245        36
7      A      23   245        37
8      A      23   245        38
9      A      99   123        119
```

For all kind of objects the values val1 and val2 are recorded with a time stamp.
How can I select all rows contaning a change in one of the value fields for each object.
Hence I want a select statement with the following result:

```
id   object   val1 val2   'time stamp'
1      Z      100  102        53
3      Z      100  103        55
4      A      99   123        23
5      A      23   245        35
9      A      99   123        119
```

Can somebody help me out with the correct sql query. Thank you.

Comment: I didn't get why `id=9` comming in your expected result. Since it's values are similar as `id=4`

Comment: id=9 is in the results because id=9 and id=4 have a different time stamp. I want to see what the values where in time. So, if a value is changed back this is relevant.

Comment: Still can get your point. timestamp is considered then why id=2 is not coming in your expected result? since timestamp of id=1 is different?

Comment: Since there is no change in Val1 and Val2 for id=1, id=2. Hence, id=2 should not be selected.

Comment: Since there is no change in Val1 and Val2 for id=4, id=9. Why id=9 is being selected? That's my point.

Comment: id=9 is being selected because val1 and val2 of object A where different at TS=39 (i.e. id=8)

Comment: @Rvd: your last clarification makes my suggested solution a no-go. You're not looking for the unique set of values an object has, you're looking for all object value pairings that were different from the immediately previous state of that object, even if the object is returning to an earlier state.

Comment: I've edited your question title to to make this clearer.

Comment: Thank you for changing the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a record with object `O` and timestamp `T`, the following query will find the values for the relevant *previous* record, i.e., the record with the largest timestamp that is still smaller than `T`:

```
SELECT val1, val2
FROM MyTable
WHERE object = O
  AND "time stamp" < T
ORDER BY "time stamp" DESC
LIMIT 1
```

By using something like this as a subquery, we can get both sets of values to compare them:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable AS T1
WHERE val1 || ',' || val2 IS NOT (SELECT T2.val1 || ',' || T2.val2
                                  FROM MyTable AS T2
                                  WHERE T2.object = T1.object
                                    AND T2."time stamp" < T1."time stamp"
                                  ORDER BY T2."time stamp" DESC
                                  LIMIT 1)
```

Creating a string from both values avoids having to use two subqueries.
This uses `IS NOT` instead of `<>` because the subquery will return `NULL` if no previous records exists.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Retracting this after OP has further clarified what he desires.  OP wants to gather rows representing a change of object state.

This would give you the unique set of object values

```
      select distinct object, val1, val2
```

Do you need an arbitrary id and a timestamp to be associated with each row for a particular purpose? That is, do you want the first occurrence? the last occurrence? of the object-value1-value2 triad?

If so you could group:

```
       select object, val1, val2, max(timestamp) as TS from T
       group by object, val1, val2
```

Then if you needed the id that belonged to the triad with max(timestamp) you can join the inline view back to the table on the four values.

```
      select t.id, foo.object, foo.val1, foo.val2, foo.TS 
      from t
      join
      (
       select object, val1, val2, max(timestamp) as TS from T
       group by object, val1, val2
      ) as foo
      on t.object = foo.object and t.val1 = foo.val1 and t.val2 = foo.val2
      and t.timestamp = foo.TS
```